# It takes long to boot

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04

I was using Ubuntu 17.10 for months and recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. My problem is that my laptop takes long to boot, it is between 4 or 5 minutes, but before it used to take 20 seconds (I have a SSD and it doesn't have partitions).
Could you make a list of step to fix it? I don't know to much about Ubuntu and it is difficult read this, because I don't speak English (Yes, there is not information about this complaint in spanish)
Thanks a lot! Hello from Perú!

Answer (score 1):

Read `man systemd-analyze`, and use `systemd-analyze blame`. From the `man` page:

```
   systemd-analyze blame prints a list of all running units, ordered by the time they took to initialize. This information may be used to optimize boot-up times. Note
   that the output might be misleading as the initialization of one service might be slow simply because it waits for the initialization of another service to complete.
```